# Deploy on Heroku error Play Framework

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.2

I have one problem.

I have one app in play framework.

I'm using play 2.2. My code is github and when I send command "git push heroku master" I have this problem:

```
    Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 574, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (512/512), done.
Writing objects: 100% (574/574), 1.45 MiB | 315 KiB/s, done.
Total 574 (delta 172), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done

 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:projetosplay.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:projetosplay.git'
```

I have aplication.conf in my github and I set my project to use play 2 in heroku:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git
```

I think is stange is that which command I type always give me the same message (example):

```
heroku open
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP.
```

Then I put: heroku open --app .git and is work.

Anybody has one idea ?

thanks !!!

Comment: Is your `application.conf` in the `conf` directory? What does your directory structure look like?

Comment: yes ! in conf directory :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps forget to create a `procfile`? You need such a file with e.g. following content:

```
web: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
```

Comment: but my play is 2.2, I think you need procfile when you is working with 1.x.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a procfile for Play 2.x applications as well